# Is there a way to execute PHP as an older version than the one installed?

Tags: php, version

I need to support some legacy code on a server where I need to be on the latest stable PHP version at all times. I can't possibly update the code base every time I upgrade so I'm wondering if there is a way to run this specific site with an older version of PHP than the one installed.

Example: I'm running PHP 5.3.3 and my code for an old site is broken. It was running perfectly on 5.2.x. Can I simply put a command in at the top of the script(s) to run it as 5.2.x so that I don't have to fix broken code the next time I upgrade to 5.4, 5.5, etc?

TL;DR: Is there a function like this:

`exec_as_php_version('5.2.14');//?`

Comment: There really shouldn't be all that much that's broken between 5.2.x and 5.3.x. The list is pretty short: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php

Comment: @ceejayoz: not on the list: any newly introduced function will cause code that defines a function with that name to abort hard. At least that's what happened to my code when date_format() was introduced in 5.2

Comment: @ceejayoz From what I found, there's no list of functions/system variables that are FULLY depreciated (as in gone-gone.) I'm maintaining old osCommerce code. It used the $HTTP_POST_VARS super everywhere, which has been depreciated since 4.1, hahaha! It's finally fully gone as of 5.3 whereas it worked in 5.2. Also, because it's a variable, it doesn't throw a depreciated error, so no one even saw it coming :(

Comment: @Michael, Good call. That was another issue for me. It failed super hard for me on date_diff() which is new to 5.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there isn't. Welcome to version dependence hell.

Edit: Now, 10 years later, this would not be terribly difficult - just run different PHP versions in separate Docker containers. It's still a bad idea to run really old PHP versions for security reasons, though.

Answer (score 3):

it is never forward compatible.

this is one solution i have seen earlier, but it is a VERY BAD IDEA: <del>http://blog.dynom.nl/archives/Multiple-PHP-versions-on-one-webserver_20091103_53.html</del> (link does not work)

Comment: Good to know. Let's hope it never gets this bad.

Comment: Link in answer is outdated. Original article is gone.

Comment: Article is available at [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223095519/http://blog.dynom.nl/archives/Multiple-PHP-versions-on-one-webserver_20091103_53.html)